# is there "upper" or "lower" functions in cmis?

Tags: java, cmis, apache-chemistry

I'm executing this query:

```
String query = "SELECT cmis:objectId,cmis:name FROM cmis:folder WHERE IN_FOLDER('" + objectId + "')";

if (filterName != null && !filterName.trim().isEmpty())
    query += " and cmis:name like '%" + filterName.trim() + "%' ";
```

and I need in the LIKE operator to both parameters to be UPPER or LOWER cased like in oracle,

is there such functions in CMIS?

Answer (score 1):

There is neither an UPPER nor a LOWER function in CMIS QL. UPPER was actually in an early CMIS spec draft, but was dropped because most repositories can't support it.

If LIKE is case sensitive depends on the repository and the setup of the repository.